# correct javascript app structure

Tags: javascript, structure

I've wrote a small example for readability.. I'm trying to get my head around proper js app structure.

I'm new to writing larger js apps. Right now, I've got a constructor, and a whole bunch of prototype functions. I always thought you're NOT supposed to call (or return) from one function to another. But now, at the bottom of my app, I'm instantiating my constructor, then having to call a bunch of functions, as well as build in conditional statements to handle the execution, which seems totally wrong.

This is the idea I've been doing:

```
function TodaysFood(b, l) 
{
    this.breakfast = b;
    this.lunch = l;
}

TodaysFood.prototype.firstMeal = function()
{
    return console.log(this.breakfast);
}

TodaysFood.prototype.secondMeal = function()
{
    return console.log(this.lunch);
}   

var app = new TodaysFood("eggs", "sandwich");

app.firstMeal();
app.secondMeal();
```

I'm wondering if this function "linking" is proper?

```
function TodaysFood(b, l) 
{
    this.breakfast = b;
    this.lunch = l;
}

TodaysFood.prototype.firstMeal = function()
{
    return this.secondMeal(this.breakfast);
}

TodaysFood.prototype.secondMeal = function(firstMeal)
{
    var twoMeals = [firstMeal, this.lunch];
    return this.whatIAte(twoMeals);
}

TodaysFood.prototype.whatIAte = function(twoMeals)
{
    return console.log(twoMeals);
}


var app = new TodaysFood("eggs", "sandwich");

app.firstMeal();
```

Stupid example, but I'm trying to understand how an app should flow. Should I be able to write my whole app in separate, but linked functions, then just kick the whole thing off by instantiating the constructor, and maybe calling one function. Or is the first example more correct -- writing independent functions, then handling the interaction between them after you've instantiate the constructor?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Unless there is a technical issue with the code, I think its only a mather of personal taste and the style in which you code your application. Maybe you could take a look at some pattern design for OOP programming that could guide you in managing your class interaction and instanciations.

Comment: Depends on what you're going to do with your object. Interesting reading maybe: [JavaScript Design patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)?

Comment: agreed with the others, that it depends, but the second example smells.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make it modular, Ala Node.js or within the browser using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

Here is a slight variation of the second example you could consider, [view fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thewiseguy99/FwUA7/)

```
var TodaysFood = function (b, l) {
    var self = this;
    this.breakfast = b;
    this.lunch = l;

    this.firstMeal = function () {
        console.log(this.breakfast);
        return self;
    };

    this.secondMeal = function () {
        console.log(this.lunch);
        return self;
    }

    this.allMeals = function () {
        return this.firstMeal().secondMeal();
    };
}

var food = new TodaysFood('eggs', 'sandwich');
food.firstMeal().secondMeal().allMeals();
```

If you plan to use node.js or RequireJS then the above could be modularized by replacing the last two test lines of code with,

`module.exports = TodaysFood;`

If this is made modular then you would remove the constructor `var TodaysFood = function(b, l) { ...` and instead accept arguments for `b` & `l` within your individual methods like `firstMeal` & `secondMeal`. This would make it static and prevent collisions with the constructor values.